# Member Variables and Functions through this pointers

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include<cstring>

using namespace std;
class String
{
    private:
    char *sptr;

    public:
    String()
    {

     }

    String(char str[])
    {
      sptr = new char[strlen(str) + 1];
      strcpy( sptr, str );
    }

    String(const String& source)
    {

        sptr = new char[strlen(source.sptr) + 1];
        strcpy( sptr, source.sptr);

    }

    ~String()
    {
      delete sptr; 
    }

    String operator=( const String& other )
    {

        if(&other!=NULL)
        {

            String tmp( other );   
            sptr = new char[strlen(tmp.sptr) + 1];
            strcpy( sptr, tmp.sptr);
        }
        return *this;    
    }
    void display()
    {

      for( char const* p = sptr; *p != '\0'; ++ p) {
            std::cout << *p;
        }
        cout<<endl;

    }


};

 int main()
 {

   String a1;
   String a2("Hello ");   
   String a3(a2);

   a2.display();
   a3.display();

    //a2.change("Java ");
    a2.display();
    a3.display();
}
```

The Output pf the program is

```
Hello Hello Hello Hello.
```

But I am undone to do the following changes in my code... i.e.. In Main () I created the following objects

```
String a1;
String a2("Hello ");   
String a3(a2);

a2.display();
a3.display();

//a2.change("Java ");
a2.display();
a3.display();
```

I want to change the the object a2(commented)  with Java and desired the output as

```
Hello Hello Java Hello
```

through deep copy of the Data members through `this` pointers.

> > How can I change the Hello string to java

Comment: I dynamically allocated a char array along with their size

Comment: You don't dynamically allocate anything in the default constructor. As such, any default-constructed instance of this object will result in undefined behavior when `delete`ing the uninitialized pointer in its destructor, and a guaranteed crash. Now, exactly what is your specific C++ question? "I want to change the object" something or other is not a question.

Comment: `if(&other!=NULL)` It's safe to assume that this condition is always `true`. If it would be `false`, you would already be in undefined behavior, so it's safe to assume it's `true` anyway.

Comment: Your assignment operator neglects to `delete` the previously allocated buffer. It will leaks memory.

Comment: @ François Andrieux help to me resolve out to this ..

Comment: @AkkiêThakur Your `String::operator =` can be written in 3 lines `{ String temp(other); std::swap(temp.sptr, sptr); return *this; }`.  Also, your `delete sptr` should be `delete [] sptr;`

Comment: @AkkiêThakur -- This 1 line, full, `main()` program using your current code causes issues: `int main() { String s; }`.  It was already mentioned by SamVarshavchik what the issue is.

Comment: i am comes over out to the problem  if(&other!=NULL)  but i am unable to change the string a2 with "Java"

Comment: @AkkiêThakur -- Why are you trying to use a faulty `String` class in the program?  First fix all of the faults already mentioned in the `String` class.  You can't build a program on a faulty foundation.

Comment: @ PaulMcKenzie Does I need to change the class name???

Comment: Your `String` class itself cannot be used to write a working program.  It has many bugs.  I don't know how much clearer to say this.  Those bugs have been mentioned already.

Comment: @Sam Varshavchik Through deep copy i want to change a2 with "Java".....

Comment: @AkkiêThakur -- Forget about the "Java" string.  The problem happens before that -- your `String` class is no good and you need to fix it.  I hate to make it more blunt, but it sounds like you're not taking any advice.

Comment: @ PaulMcKenzie no sir I will fix some of the bugs gently...

Comment: but i am asking you it will helpfull to me if i change the class name string to demo

Comment: @AkkiêThakur -- [Look at this example of your code if you need proof](https://www.ideone.com/cqPp6f).  So are you now going to believe SamV and myself about your `String` class being faulty on the simplest of operations, i.e. default construction?  How can you now build a program using a `String` class that can't even do the simplest things correctly?  Also what does changing the name of the class have anything to do with how the class operates?  You can change it to "YabbaDabbaDo" and it will still be faulty.

Comment: @ PaulMcKenzie sir i understand that.   But sir this is my assignment in which i used the class name String ...  so sir i tried many ways and everytime i got some errors at last i am asking you to please review my code and provide me some edition in the code.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/3363978/praanj Sir please check it out this problem

Comment: What is `change` supposed to do?  Why not just state `a2 = "Java ";` if all you want to do is change `a2` to now be `"Java "`?  But before you do that, you need to read my answer below, as your assignment operator is not correct.

Answer (score 2):

Your `String` class cannot be used to build a program upon, due to the faults within the `String` class.  You must fix those errors first before even thinking about using `String` as a string class.

Therefore this answer addresses how to fix `String` first -- from there, you should now be able to write the program knowing you're not working on a faulty foundation.

---

**Error 1: Default construction**

You failed to initialize `sptr` when a `String` is default constructed.  Thus when `~String()` is executed, the call to `delete` will attempt to `delete` an uninitialized pointer.

Simple 1 line `main` functions such as this one:

```
int main()
{
   String s;
} // <-- destructor of s may crash
```

will show undefined behavior and may crash, as shown by [this example](https://www.ideone.com/cqPp6f).

To fix this:

```
class String
{
   public:
     String() : sptr(nullptr) {}
   //...
};
```

Now when `delete []` is issued on `sptr`, no harm will occur since it is perfectly valid to `delete []` a `nullptr` (it becomes basically a no-op).

---

**Error 2: Faulty assignment operator**

Your `String::operator=` fails to deallocate the previous memory that was allocated.  In addition, the check for `NULL` is incorrect, since `&other` will always be `true`.

I am assuming this is the check for self-assignment, but it is not written correctly.  The check for self-assignment is done by comparing the address of the current object (`this`) with the address of the object being passed in:

`if (this != &other)`

Once you have that, then you could have written the rest of the function this way:

```
if(this != &other)
{
    String tmp( other );   
    std::swap(tmp.sptr, sptr);
}
return *this;
```

All this function does is copy `other` to a temporary `String` called `tmp`, swap out the `sptr` with the `tmp.sptr` and let `tmp` die off with the old data.  This is called the [copy / swap idiom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3279543/what-is-the-copy-and-swap-idiom), where you're just swapping out the contents of the current object with the contents of the temporary object, and letting the temporary object die off with the old contents.

Note that the check for self-assignment isn't necessary when using copy / swap, but there is no harm done in making the check (could even be a small optimization done when the check for self-assignment is present).

Edit:  The other issue is that `operator=` should return a reference to the current object, not a brand new `String` object.  The signature should be:

```
String& operator=( const String& other ) // <-- note the return type is String&
{
  //... code
  //...
  return *this;
}
```

---

**Error 3: Wrong form of `delete`**

Since you allocated using `new []`, you should be using `delete []`, not just `delete` in the destructor:

```
~String() 
{ 
   delete [] sptr;
}
```

Given all of these changes, the following code no longer has issues, as shown by the [Live Example here](https://www.ideone.com/4Hc2ab).

Now that you have a working `String` class, then you can build your application from there.

---

As to your program, you can easily change your string by using the assignment operator.  There is no need for a `change()` function:

```
String a2("Hello ");   
a2.display();
a2 = "Java ";
a2.display();
```

Since `String::operator=(const String&)` is no longer faulty with the changes above, assignment can now be done without issues.

Comment: Another one: `operator=` shouldn't return by value.

Comment: Yes, I will add that to the list.

Comment: Thanks sir I will try it with learning all your provided concepts

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie your code shows a error that nullptr was not declared in the scope..  class String
{
   public:
     String() : sptr(nullptr) {}
   //...
};                            but when i removed null ptr  from command String() : sptr(nullptr) {} it works but the null should be assigned ........  what the logic behind that

Comment: What version of C++ are you using?  You see in the online example the code compiles with no issues.  The `nullptr` is a C++ 11 keyword -- are you using a C++ 11 compliant compiler?

Comment: Also, as a replacement, you could have simply done this: `String() : sptr(0) {}`